# How to search Cyrillic/Latin 'a' or other alike characters in Cyrillic/Latin strings

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I'm implementing a filter functionality. I define whether string suits query using:

```
someString.IndexOf(someSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

But some times (of course in very rare cases) values could be like "aaa" or "ccc" and it will be more user-friendly to ignore language.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. Please clarify. Some examples would help.

Comment: when I want to show all stings containing 'c', I enter 'c' in English to the filter text box. And of cause it will return 'cat' and skip the strings like 'соя'.

Comment: Of case it is edge case, but user can misspell or the one who enter info can misspell. It is not very important, but it can be useful for user.

Comment: Why would is skip `соя`? Is the `с` a different character than the English `c`?

Comment: @Oded yes, с and c are different letters. The first is the Cyrillic letter 'es', the second is the Latin letter 'c'. I'm not sure what the OP actually wants - a user wanting to search in Cyrillic would presumably enter the former rather than the latter, using an IME or whatever.

Comment: @AakashM: may be there is no sense, I was just curious whether it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no defined correspondence between Cyrillic letters and their Latin look-alikes. The Cyrillic letter es “с” is completely distinct from the Latin letter “c”, even though probably any font that contains both of them have identical glyphs for them. In internal representation and character-level processing, they are just distinct as any two unrelated characters.

The means that should you like to accept e.g. the Cyrillic letter es “с” as the Latin letter “c”, you would need to code it yourself. But I don’t think that would be useful. Rather, if your application expects Latin letters only, your error handling routine could check whether characters from other writing systems are present and inform the user about this.